# Draggableviews with 2 separate views

Tags: views

I have 2 views. One is used to sort content of type `slider` using draggableviews. The other one displays an image field of the same `slider` content type. How can I use the weigh (sort order) of the first view in the second one?

In other words, I want to have one view that lets me sort my slider content, and another one that displays the slider content in the order defined in the first view. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'connect' both views through the (hidden) node ID:

- add the field `Content: Nid` to the fields list of your first view and check `Exclude from display` on the next screen.
- also add the field `Content: Nid` to the fields list of your first view and check `Exclude from display` on the next screen.
- add `Draggableviews: weight` to the sorting criteria of both views.
- in your second views sorting settings choose your first view under `Display sort as` to connect both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't seem to find that `Display sort as` setting.

Comment: Sorry I had another field that was causing issues. I found the option now. The strange thing is that it doesn't seem to make any difference whether I choose `Sort ascending` or `Sort descending`.

Comment: It's all right. I have set the arguments handling to `Do not use any arguments (use empty arguments)` and all is fine now. Thanks again!